# Clausius Principle vs Kelvin-Planck Principle

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, heat-engine

how to prove that the Clausius and Kelvin-Planck principle era equivalent?

In other words: How do a 100% efficiency machine would violate the second law of thermodynamics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the Kelvin-Planck statement is:

*No heat engine can operate in a cycle while transferring heat with a single heat reservoir.*

This is the same thing as saying no heat engine operating in a cycle can convert heat entirely into work.

The Clausius' statement of the second law  says:

*No refrigeration or heat pump cycle can operate without a net work input*.

This is the same thing as saying heat cannot flow naturally (without any net work being done) from a cold body to a hot body, something that has never been observed in nature.

Now let's say a heat engine takes heat $Q$ from a high temperature reservoir and converts it entirely into work work $W$ in a cycle in violation of the Kelvin Planck statement. A refrigerator then takes the work $W$ produced by the heat engine and uses it to transfer heat from a low temperature reservoir to a high temperature reservoir.  If that were possible, then the combination of the heat engine and refrigerator would do a total of zero net work to move heat from a cold reservoir to a hot reservoir. In other words, it would be possible to transfer heat from a cold body to a hot body without the need for net work input in violation of the Clausius' statement of the second law.

The above demonstrates that the violation of one law leads to the violation of the other law.

Hope this helps.